# Criar Páginas de produtos - PHP + MySql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Boa noite!

Estou fazendo uma loja virtual e gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de fazer uma página de produtos única onde o usuário clica no produto e as informações são carregadas dinamicamente. Ou se eu tiver 100 produtos cadastrados vou ter que fazer 100 páginas de produtos diferentes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria fazer uma página de produtos única onde o usuário clica no produto e as informações são carregadas dinamicamente, de acordo com as informações que há no banco.

Caso você não tenha muito conhecimento em desenvolvimento, recomendo começar algo com `PHP`, talvez você acabe fazendo algo "macarrônico" com um pouco de XGH, mas caso precise disso o mais rápido possível é o melhor caminho.

Comment: Bruno, Criei uma página chamada produto.php onde ao clicar no produto enviei o ID dele no banco pela url e consegui resgatar via $_GET nessa página.

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha conseguido!
Só não se esqueça que se for passar algo que se for enviar dados que não podem aparecer no link use $_POST.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Bruno. Nessa pagina passo somente id e categoria do produto.